# How to start nautilus maximized from command line?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, window-manager, xdotool, maximized

I can easily start Nautilus on a particular directory from command line:

```
nautilus /home/nico/Documents
```

But I want that Nautilus window to be maximized.
How to write the command line?

`nautilus` does not seem to recognize `--maximized` nor `--fullscreen`. I reluctantly tried `--geometry 1500x1500` and it does seem to have any effect.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, it can be done, but needs a tiny script. Will post in 20 minutes (I guess).

Comment: for me with resolution at 1280x1024: 'nautilus --geometry=1280x1024' launch it fullscreen as a charm. :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Start up nautilus with a maximized window

To start `nautilus` with a maximized window, you can use the script below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys

def w_list():
    try:
        pid = subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "nautilus"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
        w_list = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
        return [l.split()[0] for l in w_list if pid in l]
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

relevant1 = w_list()
subprocess.Popen(["nautilus", "--new-window"])

t = 0
while t < 30:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    relevant2 = w_list()
    if all([relevant2 != None, relevant1 != None]):
        new = [w for w in relevant2 if not w in relevant1]
        if new:
            subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "windowsize", new[0], "100%", "100%"])
            break
    relevant1 = relevant2
    t += 1
```

#### How to use

- **The script uses both `xdotool` and `wmctrl`**, the first one to list *new* windows of the targeted application, the last one because I prefer the way `xdotool`resizes windows.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl
  ```
- Then copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `start_maximized.py`
- Test- run the script by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/start_maximized.py
  ```

  Now nautilus will start up with a new *maximized* window.
- Add, if you like, the command as a quicklist (right- click) item to the `Files` (nautilus) launcher in the Unity Launcher.

### 2. Generalized version; start up *any* application maximized

You can startup *any* GUI application (+ their arguments) in the generalized script below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys

appcommand = sys.argv[1:]
app = appcommand[0]
startup = (" ").join(appcommand)

def w_list():
    try:
        pid = subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", app]).decode("utf-8").strip()
        w_list = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
        return [l.split()[0] for l in w_list if pid in l]
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

relevant1 = w_list()
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", startup])

t = 0
while t < 30:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    relevant2 = w_list()
    if all([relevant2 != None, relevant1 != None]):
        new = [w for w in relevant2 if not w in relevant1]
        if new:
            subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "windowsize", new[0], "100%", "100%"])
            break
    relevant1 = relevant2
    t += 1
```

#### To use it

- Do the setup exactly as above (including installing `wmctrl` and `xdotool`,
  but additionally use the targeted application (+ possible arguments) as an argument to run the script.

  For example:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/start_maximized.py nautilus --new-window
  ```

  or:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/start_maximized.py gedit
  ```

---

### Additionaly, add the option to a quicklist

[image]

You can easily add the option to the `nautilus` quicklist. Assuming you use the second (generalized) version:

- Copy the global `nautilus.desktop` file locally:

  which is on **14.04 and 14.10** : nautilus.desktop:

  ```
  cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
  ```

  and on **15.04 and 15.10** : org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop

  ```
  cp /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
  ```
- Open the file with (e.g.) gedit, look for the line:

  ```
  Actions=Window;
  ```

  Change it into:

  ```
  Actions=Window;Open a maximized window;
  ```

  Add to the very end of the file:

  ```
  [Desktop Action Open a maximized window]
  Name=Open a maximized window
  Exec=python3 '/path/to/start_maximized.py' nautilus --new-window
  OnlyShowIn=Unity;
  ```
- Save and close the file.
- Log out and back in.

Now you have a quicklist option like in the image.

### Conceptual explanation

To maximize *an existing* window is not very difficult. Both `wmctrl` and `xdotool` offer options to do so.

The issue is that if you want to maximize a newly created window, you don't know the window id yet when you give the command. Therefore the script practices the following procedure:

1. make a list of the currently existing windows of the targeted application (if any)
2. give the command to open the application (or a new window of a running application)
3. keep an eye on *new* windows of the application to appear
4. if the new window appears, it is apparently our candidate to maximize -> maximize it.

This way, we can "smartly" maximize the application's new window, that will work no matter the computer is slow (occupied with a heavy job for example) or fast.

Finally, the script has a built in safety time-limit, to prevent waiting for ever in case the application fails to start up for some reason. After appr. 15 seconds, the script gives up and exits an way.

Comment: `python3 /home/nico/p/start_maximized.py nautilus --new-window` gives me `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wmctrl'` at line 18.

Comment: +1 This works great for me :) @NicolasRaoul `sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl` is required to run the script.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten to install these packages, it works great now!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul perfect, glad it works :) I will add some explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Nautilus remembers the windows size.
Start it normally and maximize it, then close it.

Now when you type `nautilus` in terminal, it will open up maximised.
Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Oh, so there is no way to only sometimes launch it maximized, but the rest of the time at a smaller size, right? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Am not sure. Unless you target specific nautilus windows using compiz.